# How do I have an admin link work for an authenticated user (people tab for admins) [Drupal]

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I need to have a link that has /admin/people on it successfully have access for an authenticated user. I already tried contextual links and the bypass permission settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you navigate to /admin/people/roles you should be able to edit/create custom permission.

[image]

Comment: I'm glad I could help.